# How to cut the ends off of a string without losing the spaces?

Tags: python, list

So I've got a list where each element looks something like this:

```
mlist = ['|             | |   |']
```

What I need to do, is chop the two vertical lines off each end, then turn it back into a string, but I can't lose any of those spaces.

I tried this:

```
for i in mlist:
        templist = i.split()
        templist.pop(0)
        templist.pop()
        mlist[count] = templist
        count += 1
```

But that just cut out all of the spaces.

Comment: `i[1:-1]` should do.

Comment: We should point out that `str.split()` (no arguments) splits the string using "one or more whitespace characters" as a delimiter (i.e. considers clusters of whitespace (space, tab, return, newline, etc.) as boundaries for the INTERESTING parts), in case this ever comes up in a search.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove pipes from the beginning and end:

```
mlist = [elem.strip('|') for elem in mlist]
```

This removes the `|` characters only if present, and will remove more than one if repeated at the start or end.

You could also use slicing to remove the first and last character, regardless of what is there:

```
mlist = [elem[1:-1] for elem in mlist]
```

Demo:

```
>>> mlist = [
...     '|             | |   |',
...     '|||           | |  ||',
...     '              | |    ',
... ]
>>> [elem.strip('|') for elem in mlist]
['             | |   ', '           | |  ', '              | |    ']
>>> [elem[1:-1] for elem in mlist]
['             | |   ', '||           | |  |', '             | |   ']
```

Note the differences here; the second element had multiple pipes at the start and end, and the last element had none.

Comment: Following all your answers, I've begin to use your words *As is the teacher, so is the student*

Answer (score 4):

I think slicing serves the purpose

```
mlist = [i[1:-1] for i in mlist]
```

A small demo

```
>>> mlist = ['|             | |   |','|            | | | |']
>>> [i[1:-1] for i in mlist]
['             | |   ', '            | | | ']
```